# JavaScript, React and Chakra-UI link: Replace text when link clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm writing code that empties box from text and replaces that text with new text when link is clicked. But for now it's only adding text below the old text.
This must be done only with JavaScript if possible.
I have tried to find information from everywhere I know and haven't found anything that helps.

Here's my code so far:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import LocalStorageService from '../../../AvainiaTools/LocalStorageService.js';
import AvainiaCore from 'avainia-core-api';

//Components
import ApartmentReview from '../../partials/ApartmentReview/ApartmentReview.js';

//Chakras
import { Box, Divider, Text, Flex, Link } from '@chakra-ui/layout';
import { Image } from '@chakra-ui/image';


class CompanyPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tab: 'default',
      environment: 'environment',
      security: 'security',
      helps: 'helps',
      faqs: 'faqs'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

}

render() {
  const params = `${this.props.match.params.id}/${this.props.match.params.projectId}`;

  const environment = this.state.environment;

  const security = this.state.security;
  const helps = this.state.helps;
  const faqs = this.state.faqs;

  return (
    <Box bg="white" mb="4">
      <Box>
      <Box p={[4, 8, 4, 8]}>
        <Text fontWeight="bold" fontSize="16">Testdata</Text>
        <Divider display={{ base: "none", md: "block"}} width="100%"  />

        <Box bg="lightgray" p={[4, 8, 4, 8]} ml="800" mt="-4" mb="10">
        <Flex mb="4">
          <Link
          onClick={() => this.setState({ environment: !environment})}
          color="black" fontSize="14">Environment</Link>
        </Flex>
        <Flex mb="4">
          <Link
          onClick={() => this.setState({ security: !security})}
          color="black" fontSize="14">Safety at work</Link>
        </Flex>
        <Flex mb="4">
          <Link
          onClick={() => this.setState({ helps: !helps})}
          color="black" fontSize="14">Useful Links</Link>
        </Flex>
        <Link
        onClick={() => this.setState({ faqs: !faqs})}
        color="black" fontSize="14">FAQ</Link>
      </Box>

      <Box marginLeft="3">
      { this.state.tab == 'default' &&
      <Box bg="white" marginTop="-230" marginRight="445">
        <Text fontSize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        <br></br>
        <Text fontSize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        <br></br>
        <Text fontsize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        <br></br>
        <Text fontsize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        <br></br>
        <Text fontsize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        <br></br>
        <Text fontsize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        <br></br>
        <Text fontWeight="bold" fontSize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        <br></br>
        <Text fontsize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        <br></br>
        <Text fontsize="14" margin-left="4">Testdata</Text>
        </Box>
        }

        {this.state.environment !== 'environment' &&
        <Box marginRight="445">
          <Box bg="white" w="100%">
            <Text fontSize="14">Testidata</Text>
          </Box>
          </Box>
          }

          {this.state.security !== 'security' &&
          <Box marginRight="445">
          <Box bg="white" w="100%">
            <Text fontSize="14">Testdata</Text>
          </Box>
          </Box>
          }

          {this.state.helps !== 'helps' &&
          <Box marginRight="445">
          <Box bg="white" w="100%">
            <Text fontSize="14">Testdata</Text>
          </Box>
          </Box>
          }

          {this.state.faqs !== 'faqs' &&
          <Box marginRight="445">
          <Box bg="white" w="100%">
            <Text fontSize="14">Testdata</Text>
          </Box>
          </Box>
          }

        </Box>
      </Box>
      </Box>
      <Box p={[4, 8, 4, 8]}>
      <Image src="https://via.placeholder.com/1050x195" alt="placeholder" />
      </Box>
      </Box>
  )
}
}


export default withRouter(CompanyPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to edit the codes of links' onClick so that sub-pages' text replaces original when link is clicked. There's my new link codes:

```
<Box bg="lightgray" p={[4, 8, 4, 8]} ml="800" mt="-4" mb="10">
    <Flex mb="4">
      <Link
      onClick={() => this.setState({ environment: !environment, tab: !environment})}
      color="black" fontSize="14">Environment</Link>
    </Flex>
    <Flex mb="4">
      <Link
      onClick={() => this.setState({ security: !security, tab: !security, })}
      color="black" fontSize="14">Safety at work</Link>
    </Flex>
    <Flex mb="4">
      <Link
      onClick={() => this.setState({ helps: !helps, tab: !helps})}
      color="black" fontSize="14">Useful links</Link>
    </Flex>
    <Link
    onClick={() => this.setState({ faqs: !faqs, tab: !faqs})}
    color="black" fontSize="14">FAQs</Link>
  </Box>
```

But when I click link in the sub-page, it adds new text below old one. It should replace old sub-page's next with new sub-page's text. How should I edit my code?